# Angular POST request received in NET Core Api as Null

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

Im POSTing some data via Angular 6, but my Core API keeps returning nulls:

Request:

```
{"id":0,"name":"test","weight":2,"frequency":2,"activityTypeModelId":3}
```

Response:

```
{id: 0, name: null, weight: 0, frequency: 0, activityTypeModelId: 0}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult Add([FromForm]Model model)
{
    return new JsonResult(model);
}
```

Angular, using HttpClient:

```
add(Model: model) {
     return this.http.post(this.addUrl, model);
}
```

API Model:

```
public class Model
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
    public int ActivityTypeModelId { get; set; }
}
```

TS Model:

```
 export class Model{
   id?: number;
   name?: string;
   weight?: number;
   frequency?: number;
   activityTypeModelId?: number;
 }
```

Everything works fine when I'm using Postman. I already tried with [FromBody]. Where is the problem?

Comment: Your action is returning something named `newCircumstance`, what is that?

Comment: What do you see in the network tab of developer console in your browser? Are you able to see `request body` over there?

Comment: When you break in the C# Action is Model populated? When you look at Browser Dev tools what is getting submitted?

Comment: @R.Richards , i forgot to change that name here after pasting. I changed it in the edit.

Comment: @AmitChigadani No, there is no requestbody.

Comment: @RichardHubley Its populated with 0 and strings with nulls

Comment: How did you try with `[FromBody]?` I made a test with this [project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3hhO2HD8Kj6VHueOO), fail to reproduce your issue. The key difference is `public IActionResult Add([FromBody]Model model)`. What is `this.http`? Share us reqeust headers.

Comment: @TaoZhou `this.http`  is the HttpClient from Angular, the request body: `{id: null, name: "test", weight: 2, frequency: 0, activityTypeModelId: 15}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know why, but this fixed my issue:

I created a header:

```
 const header = new HttpHeaders()
     .set('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

Changed the POST function by adding a header and JSON.Stringyfy the object:

```
 add(model: Model): Observable<Model> {
     const body = JSON.stringify(c);
     return this.http.post<Model>(this.addUrl, body, { headers: header} );
   }
```

Changed `[FromForm]` to `[FromBody]`.

Adding `JSON.stringify(model)` in the parameters of the `http.post` was not working.

JSON that is working with the CORE Api:

`{"name":"test","weight":2,"activityTypeModelId":15}`

JSON that is not working with the CORE Api:

`{name:"test",weight:2,activityTypeModelId:15}`

Without the header I encountered a 415 error from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return this.http.post(this.addUrl, JSON.stringify(model) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that, in .NET Core 2.1 is (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

```
HttpPost("[action]")]
//see that I put [FromBody]
public IActionResult Add([FromBody]Model model)
{
    //OK is one of several IActionResult 
    return OK(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the problem was that I was trying to bind to an interface:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(bool), StatusCodes.Status200OK]
public bool SaveResponse([FromBody]ISaveRequestViewModel request) =>
    Service.SaveResponse(request.Responses);
```

I fixed it by changing it to a class:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(bool), StatusCodes.Status200OK]
public bool SaveResponse([FromBody]SaveRequestViewModel request) =>
    Service.SaveResponse(request.Responses);
```

This model also had to use classes instead of interfaces:

```
public class SaveRequestViewModel
{
    public List<IQuestionResponseViewModel> Responses { get; set; }
}
```

Became

```
public class SaveRequestViewModel
{
    public List<QuestionResponseViewModel> Responses { get; set; }
}
```

I guess the model binder just doesn't work with interfaces.