# Cant pass parameter to API

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, rest

I'm running a REST API service that has this action :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public FooResponse DoFoo(FooRequest request)
    //public FooResponse DoFoo([FromBody] FooRequest request)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

My request:

```
public class FooRequest
{
    public string FooId;
}
```

I have an Angular client, that's making this call :

```
startFoo(fooId: string)
{
const url = `${this.baseUrl}StartFoo`;
const params = new HttpParams()
.set('FooId', fooId);
console.log(`params : ${params}`);

const result = this.httpClient.post<fooItem>(url, {params}).toPromise();
return result;
}
```

When I make the call from PostMan, the FooId is populated, when I call it from Angular, the endpoint is hit, but the param is always null. When I look in the console log, the parameters is there.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103337/angular-post-request-received-in-net-core-api-as-null) solution, but it did not resolve my issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try put set() away from instantiation

` const params = new HttpParams();
params.set('FooId', fooId);`

Comment: @Leandro, same result.

Comment: You don't want to use `HttpParams` in your case, you are looking for `FooRequest` so build your object similar to that and pass it in assuming its just `Id` just pass in `{ FooId: fooId }` and use `[FromBody]` on your action

Comment: i think you can make a concat parameters directly on your URL, like:

`const result = this.httpClient.post<fooItem>(url+'?FoodId='+foodId)`

Comment: You should look at your request's detail in the browser's dev tools, network tab. You can see if your parameter is sent.

Comment: @htn, thanks. I did so, and the request payload was empty. With the accepted answer below, I could, for the first time, actually see a payload.

Comment: `params` is not for paypload. It is for url's parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add [FromBody] attribute in method .

```
  [HttpPost]
  public FooResponse DoFoo([FromBody] FooRequest request)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

While you send the request to api, your request body must be in json format.

```
var fooRequest = { FooId : 1};


const result = this.httpClient.post<fooItem>(url, JSON.stringify(fooRequest) ).toPromise();
```

I did not try, I guess that It will work.

Comment: You do not need to use `JSON.stringify`